# Adjusting S column in siunitx

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I am a beginner in LaTeX, trying to use it for an industrial test report. I have numerous tables in my document, and  I have recently discovered the capabilities of `siunitx`. I would like to use `S` column whenever possible. I have tentatively modified one table to experiment, but I find that the options I have choosen make a table with fairly large columns and some no longer fit the page. Also, it does not seem the `S` columns are well centered in the attached example.  What fix can be applied?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside,11pt, english, numbers=noenddot, captions=tableheading]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Usual fonts
\usepackage{tgheros,textcomp}% Fonts
\usepackage{siunitx}% Handling Si units
\usepackage{tabularx} % More elaborate form of tables
\usepackage{multirow} %handling of fusionned cells in tables
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}%selecting default font (clone of helvetica)
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
%BEGIN CONFIG 2 CAVITIES--------------
\newcommand{\ConfigTwoGang}[3]{%
AAAAAAA &   1-20        &#1     &1-20       &#1\\
BBBBBBBB    &   1-8     &#2     &1-20       &#1\\
CCCCCCC&    1-20        &#1     &Power      &#3\\
}%
%-------------------------------------------------------
%END CONFIG 2 CAVITIES--------------
%------------------------------------------------------
% BEGIN INSERT  TABLE TWO CAV 
\newcommand{\TableIRTwoGang}[4]{%
\begin{table}[#4]%
\noindent 
\begin{center}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center,table-figures-integer = 4}
\caption{Insulation resistance (\si{\mega\ohm}) - 2 gang versions}
\begin{tabular}{|c|cS[table-comparator = true]|cS[table-comparator = true]|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Part number}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{{Cavity 1}}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{{Cavity 2}}\\
%\hline
&Position&{Ins. Res.}&Position&{Ins. Res.}\\
\hline\hline
\ConfigTwoGang{#1}{#2}{#3}%
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
}%
%------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\TableIRTwoGang{> 1500}{> 2000}{> 5000}{H}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What fix can be applied?

In the MWE you provide, you make only minimal use of the capabilities of the `S` column type that's provided by the `siunitx` package. In such a case, it may be best to just use the instruction

```
\sisetup{table-parse-only}
```

and omit all further options. The following, slightly modified form of your MWE shows that with this option in place, the contents of the two `S` columns are nicely centered, which is what I understand you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt, english, 
   numbers=noenddot, captions=tableheading]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros,textcomp}% Fonts
\usepackage{siunitx}% Handling Si units
\usepackage{tabularx} % More elaborate form of tables
\usepackage{multirow} %handling of fused cells in tables
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}%select default font (clone of helvetica)

\newcommand{\ConfigTwoGang}[3]{%
  AAAAAAA  &   1-20    &#1   &1-20    &#1\\      
  BBBBBBBB &   1-8     &#2   &1-20    &#1\\      
  CCCCCCC  &   1-20    &#1   &Power   &#3\\    }

\newcommand{\TableIRTwoGang}[4]{%
  \begin{table}[#4]%
    \sisetup{table-parse-only}
    \caption{Insulation resistance (\si{\mega\ohm}) --- 2 gang versions}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|cS|cS|}
      \hline
      \multirow{2}{*}{Part number}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Cavity 1}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Cavity 2}\\            
        & Position & {Ins.\ Res.} 
        & Position & {Ins.\ Res.}\\          
        \hline\hline
      \ConfigTwoGang{#1}{#2}{#3}%
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
}

\begin{document}
\TableIRTwoGang{> 1500}{> 2000}{> 5000}{ht!}
\end{document}
```

**A separate comment**: With your current font choice commands, viz.,

```
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

you end up having (a clone of) `Helvetica` as the text font and `Computer Modern Sans` as the math font. An inspection of the weights and shapes of the characters in columns 1, 2, and 4 vs. those in columns 3 and 5 reveals some differences; these differences aren't drastic, but they *are* noticeable. (For instance, the glyph "1" has a "footer" in `Computer Modern Sans` but has no footer in `Helvetica`.) Some people may find the use of two different sans-serif fonts within one table a bit distracting. If you need to use sans-serif fonts throughout your document, you may want to employ the `arev` font package, which sets both text and math fonts in a sans-serif font which, IMHO, is very well suited for the display of numeric material in tables. The image below shows the same table as before, but now with the command `\usepackage{arev}` used in lieu of `\usepackage{tgheros}`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks much better. It seems my original options were not optimum for some reason. Using S columns gave the > sign a much more suitable glyph, a more uniform alignment in tables and some other nice ways to format the numbers properly, as I use other Siunitx options in other tables, but I had not seen this problem. Concerning the math font, I use \usepackage{sfmath} in my preamble   to eliminate math fonts everywhere, but this is not a standard package, and I have removed it from the MWE.

Comment: The use of \usepackage{tgheros} had been suggested to me by Joseph Wright as a solution to a problem I had with the Ohm symbol not matching well the helvetica font. I have not heard of arev before, but will give it a try. Rgds

Comment: Good idea to use the `sfmath` package, as you'll now get `Helvetica` consistently in both text and math. If you have very different layout needs in different tables, I'd venture to opint that it's probably a good idea to keep the global `\sisetup` options to a minimum and, instead, use separate `\sisetup` commands inside each `table` environment.

Comment: I agree it is not easy to distinguish what \sisetup options should go to the preamble and which ones should go in every table... The large number of tables I have in the document leads me to try to put as much as possible in the general options....

Comment: Well, as the second table image shows, the `arev` package has its own shortcoming: no `Ohm` symbol either! In consequence, this symbol has to be "borrowed" from Computer Modern (Roman) as well. Not perfect, for sure. The combination of `tgheros` and `sfmath` should do the trick for you.

Comment: Yes it seems. I had been trying to solve the Ohm symbol problem (standard and bold) for a long time, and the use of \usepackage{tgheros, sfmath}, with the  other changes you suggested,  seems to solve the problem nicely.